# how to find location name respective mobile number in android

Tags: android

I am new to android programming.I want to find the location name of the mobile number when i select any phone number from contacts .every application is explaining like how to get current location.I have tried to get the location name based on mobile IMEI number.I don't know how to do this properly.can i get the location using gps or network service.please give me the complete description along with example.

Comment: What effort you put for this?

Comment: If I understand your question - you want to get your client's location using his cell number?